# Ubuntu 12.04 freezes randomly

Tags: 12.04, dell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I'm running Dell Inspiron 15R with Intel HD graphics, 3 GB RAM, 64-bit operating OS. The problem is my computer freezes randomly, the touchpad gets stuck, nothing to do but to shut down by manually pressing the power button.

I made a clean install today of the Ubuntu OS and 30 minutes later, there is no overheating in my laptop nor any loud fan noise. What could cause this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running a diagnostic test on your hard drive and also try a diagnostic test on your RAM. I never used Linux a lot but I think the same tasks required to troubleshoot and repair problems with Windows would also apply to Linux, just different ways of doing things.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon, ill try to do a ram and hdd diagnostic test and post the results if thats whats causing the problem.